# sending keys to a difficult element in selenium (Python)

Tags: selenium

I'm using selenium. The source code of the element is:

```
<input tabindex="5" class="buttonStyle" onclick="submitForm('SEARCH','');return false" type="submit" value="Search">
```

The css shows

```
input[type='submit']
```

The code I use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']").click();

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit']").click()
```

Both don't work as expected.
The code below does not work as well:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@onclick='submitForm('SEARCH','');return false']").click()
InvalidSelectorException: Message: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[@onclick='submitForm('SEARCH','');return false'] because of the following error:
Error: Bad token, expected: ] got: SEARCH
```

I used the XPATH checker on internet explorer (the favourite page named MRI). It shows the target element. However the above code does not work.
I'm using Jupyter Notebook, Selenium and Internet Explorer (the page can only be opened in IE)

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that the given `XPATH` is not valid. You seem to have an extra ']' in the xpath. Please update it.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit']")))
button.click()
```

Add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```